# Applet and JSF Integration - example

Tags: applet

Can we implement javascript into applet/swing?If yes how? please give some basic/small example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "implement" it as in manipulating its components, you can however use JavaScript to dynamically change the `<param>` tags of the `<applet>` element, and define the applet to respond to that.

Comment: Hi,Suppose i have a applet window and i want to implement date time picket into it,please can you tell ,how can i do it?I tried it through swings component,bt i found it very difficult to implement it .

Comment: A date picker has **nothing** to do with applet/DHTML interaction.  Date pickers can be done in Swing/JApplet, but there are also a number of JS implementations available.  I suggest you use a JavaScript date picker and leave the applet out of it.

Comment: I second @AndrewThompson notion.

Comment: Thx Andrew,Actually in my application, there is a  dynamic graph generating (like Google finance) on basis of some data tht come from some other system.I have to implement a date picker to view graph between some time period.I have done it through JButton,when user will click on Button one date picker frame will be opened and now user can select date time.Now please can u tell same thing how can i implement through Java Script,because i dont think i can implement java Script code into Applet/Swing.

Comment: Did you try [jGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/)? I hear it's pretty sweet. I generally dislike the use of applets because not all computers have Java installed (much less then JavaScript in browsers anyway).